# How to rollback all the commits in Oracle DB

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-administration, rollback, savepoints

Recently I made a mistake, that, all the tables in my oracle database were dropped (running drop command from SQL Developer tool) in a sequence of all transactions unbeknownst to me that I was dropping tables at the wrong database. Each time I dropped a set of tables, I committed the operations. By the time, I realized that I have dropped the tables at the wrong DB, I was too late to rollback, since it rolled back the last operation only. I searched online as well, and found SavePoints to be the resolution, but I had no savepoints configured. I had the backup of all the tables taken 2 days before, so, I ran scripts from there and made lost changes for the past 2 days.
Is there any other way that I take to get my DB state back. I have made it a practice to make savepoints while performing such operations though. But, I am still confused. One who doesn't know about savepoints will lose all the data.

Comment: Savepoints and rollback won't help you anyway; DDL operations including `drop` [implicitly commit](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/cncpt/transactions.html#GUID-510DF997-BA9C-4431-95EF-A0622881EC9C). Have you looked at [flashback](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/FLASHBACK-TABLE.html)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DDL statements like `drop` do an implicit commit so you cannot `rollback` to undrop a table.  Nor would a savepoint help you since that only lets you go back to an earlier point in the current transaction.

If you have merely dropped a table, assuming you haven't disabled the recycle bin, you can simply do a [flashback drop](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMQS/GUID-1DE547D1-3AF0-4269-8BAA-4C298EC05905.htm)

```
flashback table <<table name>> to before drop
```

If you have a more complicated script that is doing more than just dropping tables, you may want to set a [restore point](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/backup.112/e10642/flashdb.htm#BRADV589) prior to running the script.  You could then flashback the entire database to that restore point if something goes wrong.

```
create restore point <<your restore point name>>

<<run your script>>

flashback database to restore point <<your restore point name>>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Justin. I tried flashback. Could there be any reason flashback doesn't work?

Comment: @Ashish - Which command did you try?  `flashback table`?  Or `flashback drop`?  What does "doesn't work" mean?  Did you get an error?  If so, what was the error?

Comment: @Ashish Flashback has to be enabled in your database. We don't enable it do to the additional overhead.

Comment: @BrianLeach - "Flashback" is a broad term for a number of different features that are controlled by a number of different settings.  You have to enable flashback logs to be able to do a `flashback database`.  You do not need to do anything to enable `flashback table`.  You can disable the recycle bin which will prevent `flashback table` from working.  There are also flashback queries which use `undo` rather than flashback logs so those are configured differently.